# Ordered-pair graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a (finite) set $S$ and the digraph $G$ with vertex set $V(G) = S^2$, i.e. the ordered pairs over $S$. Let there be an arrow from $(v,w)$ to $(x,y)$ iff $v = y$.

How can these "ordered pair graphs" be abstractly characterized (up to isomorphism)?

Some necessary conditions for a graph to be an ordered pair graph are obvious:

1. there is an $n$ such that there are exactly $n^2$ vertices
2. there are exactly $n$ vertices $v$ with $v\rightarrow v$
3. each vertex has exactly $n$ incoming and $n$ outgoing arrows
4. the relation $x \sim_1  y$ which holds iff $(\exists z)\ x
       \rightarrow z \wedge\  y \rightarrow z$ is an equivalence relation
5. the relation $x \sim_2 y$ which holds iff $(\exists z)\ z
       \rightarrow x \wedge\  z \rightarrow y$ is an equivalence relation

> Can it be shown that some of the conditions above depend on others, esp. on (4) and/or (5)?
>
> Can this set of conditions be completed to characterize ordered pair
>   graphs up to isomorphism?

Comment: These are the 2-dimensional [De Bruijn graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph).

Comment: Thanks, Henning! Great hint.